# Overcoming the 5TB Azure File Storage share limitation

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-files

Azure File Storage  has a limitation to 5 TB per file share,  is there a way to aggregate multiple Azure file storage shares so they appear as one drive

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to expand beyond 5TB per storage file volume. You'd need to create and use multiple SMB shares. I don't know if there's a tool to let you map multiple smb volumes into the same logical file storage area.

Note: Direct blob storage has no such 5TB limit, as you can store up to 500TB of blobs per storage account.